# How To Compare Two Strings If they are rearranged

Tags: java, string, char, equals

I wanted to know how can I compare two rearranged strings 
E.g if String a="string" ,String b="tsrngi" ... If  I compare a.equals(b), It will return false because of order of characters... I want it to return true because characters are same but only order is different.. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sort them, then compare. To sort, use something like:

```
char[] content = unsorted.toCharArray();
java.util.Arrays.sort(content);
String sorted = new String(content);
```

Comment: It's elegant, but it also takes `O(n lg n)` for an operation that should take `O(n)`.

Answer (score 6):

I really like JRL's solution, since it's quite elegant. At the same time, I feel that because there is a solution that is an order of complexity better that I should share it. It's less elegant, but it's `O(n)` instead of `O(n lg n)`.

```
if(str1.length() != str2.length()) return false; 
Map<Character, Integer> counts = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

for(int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
    // add 1 for count for str1
    if(counts.contains(str1.charAt(i)) {
        counts.put(str1.charAt(i),counts.get(star1.charAt(i)) + 1);
    } else {
        counts.put(str1.charAt(i),1);
    }
    // sub 1 for count for str2
    if(counts.contains(str2.charAt(i)) {
        counts.put(str2.charAt(i),counts.get(str2.charAt(i)) - 1);
    } else {
        counts.put(str2.charAt(i),-1);
    }
}
// when you're done, all values in the map should be 0. If they
// aren't all 0, you don't have equal-arranged strings.
for(Integer i : counts.values()) {
    if(i.intValue() != 0) return false;
}
// we made it this far, we know it's true
return true;
```

Comment: +1 In our craft, "elegant" has many meanings, but imo, "gracefully efficient in execution" trumps "expressed in less instructions" pretty much every time.

Comment: Well it's possible that his method will be faster in some cases anyway. For small sets, mine will incur heavy autoboxing and object creation penalties. (Although someone who was sufficiently concerned with it could create primitive map alternatives to get around that)

Comment: Or a wrapper could be written which would call either, depending on size of data.  Also, note that neither solution includes an unequal length check, which could conveniently be put in the wrapper.

Comment: Umm, isn't the first line in mine an unequal length check? And yes, I think an experimental determined threshold of when his outperforms mine would be beneficial. Something like `if(str1.length() < THRESHOLD) return equalSort(str1,str2); return equalMap(str1,str2);`

Comment: Hah.  More haste, less speed.  Apologies.  Missed it.